# Есть способ сделать чтобы при запуске программы ставился определенный язык по умолчанию?

Tags: c++

Нужно чтобы язык ввода при запуске программы ставился по умолчанию. Например, мне нужен английский, но при запуске программы ставится русский. Я конечно могу каждый раз переключать, но это вызывает некоторые трудности.

Comment: `LANGID GetSystemDefaultUILanguage();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное вам нужен [ActivateKeyboardLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-activatekeyboardlayout)